# Titanium android app going white blank when relaunched from background

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

When titanium android app is running smooth. I didn’t find any crash or run time error. But the problem is when I minimise it and reopen it from background after some time(1 hr or 2 hr) its going white blank. Any help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the logic in your application.  Are you adding and removing UI elements on the screen after the background process runs?  Sounds like you are looking at a window or view with a white background.  I think if you don't assign a background, it comes up black.

Often find that when this happens to me, it is some view I didn't set a height and size for.  It covers over or pushes down all the other UI elements so it appears blank when is reality the other UI elements are beyond the edge of the screen.

To troubleshoot, I often give my views and windows different colors to figure out exactly what view, or window, I'm looking at.  Often it isn't the one I suspected or a view that is larger than I wanted it to be.